# Reportlab: rebuild a document after changing the margins?

Tags: python, reportlab

In a program I'm writing for a friend's business, I am using the reportlab module to build PDF documents for various reports.  In most cases, the report can be contained on a single page, but it may span across two pages in some rare circumstances.  In those rare situations, what I'd like to do is re-format the page with smaller top and bottom margins to see if I can get it to fit on a single page.  If not, I'll just use minimal margins and let it span two pages.

To build a report, I'm creating an instance of the `SimpleDocTemplate` class.  After passing in all my flowables to the `build` method, I found that I can query the `page` attribute to see how many pages it used.  Here's the first thing I tried:

```
parts = []
path = "/path/to/my/file.pdf"
# ... a bunch of code that appends various flowables to 'parts'
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(path, pagesize=landscape(letter))
doc.build(parts)
# Shrink the margins while it's more than one page and the margins are above zero
while doc.page > 1 and not any([doc.topMargin <= 0, doc.bottomMargin <= 0]):
    # Decrease the page margins and rebuild the page
    doc.topMargin -= inch * .125
    doc.bottomMargin -= inch * .125
    doc.build(parts)
# If the margins are nil and we're still at 2 or more pages, use minimal margins
if doc.page > 1:
    doc.topMargin = inch * .25
    doc.bottomMargin = inch * .25
    doc.build(parts)
```

I assumed that calling the `build` method with the same parts after changing the margins would recalculate everything.  However, after much trial and error, I learned that the `parts` list that's passed to the `build` method is essentially stripped clean during the build process, leaving `parts` as an empty list.  Once this was passed back to the `build` method again, it created a document with zero pages.

To work around that, I tried building the document using a copy of the `parts` list:

```
doc.build(parts[:])
```

That led to some bizarre exception, so I tried a deep copy using the `copy` module:

```
doc.build(copy.deepcopy(parts))
```

This didn't throw any exceptions, but didn't change the margins, either.

Getting a little desperate, I probed deeper into the `SimpleDocTemplate` attributes and found a method named `_calc`.  Thinking that this might recalculate the page, I tried calling it after changing the margins.  It didn't throw any exceptions, but didn't work, either.

The only way I've managed to make it work is to use the `deepcopy` process and build brand new documents every time I tweak the margins:

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(path, pagesize=landscape(letter))
doc.build(copy.deepcopy(parts))
# Shrink the margins while it's more than one page and the margins are above zero
while doc.page > 1 and not any([doc.topMargin <= 0, doc.bottomMargin <= 0]):
    doc.topMargin -= inch * .125
    doc.bottomMargin -= inch * .125
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(path, pagesize=landscape(letter),
                            topMargin = doc.topMargin,
                            bottomMargin = doc.bottomMargin)
    doc.build(copy.deepcopy(parts))
# If the margins are nil and we're still at 2 or more pages, use minimal margins
if doc.page > 1:
    doc.topMargin = inch * .25
    doc.bottomMargin = inch * .25
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(path, pagesize=landscape(letter),
                            topMargin = doc.topMargin,
                            bottomMargin = doc.bottomMargin)
    doc.build(copy.deepcopy(parts))
```

However, it feels like a lot of unnecessary work to go that route.  I'd prefer to just change the document margins and tell the document to rebuild itself using those new values, but I can't figure out how.  Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very interesting question. However, I believe you have already hit upon the correct way to do this in ReportLab. The build process is a one-time thing that you can do to a document because it produces side-effects that you cannot go back from. Thankfully, as you've already discovered, although somewhat annoying, it's not that hard to do what you want.